# Guide a daemon process output to console stdout or stderr

Tags: stdout, daemon, stderr

I've a daemon process periodically output the info to log file, how can i get these info output to console stdout or stderr?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that on Linux? Or Mac?

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are per process. Did you want to constantly monitor the output? In that case something like `tail -f output.log` might help.

Comment: it's on Linux @WhiteViking, and thx song-gao